# Word or phrase for wanting someone to fail, but only for the lesson it will bring

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I am looking for a word or phrase for wanting someone to fail, but only to teach them a lesson.

It's not easy to explain. For example, when you tell a child, "Don't run down the hill or you will fall," but they continue anyway. To prevent them from doing this in the future on a bigger hill with a much more harsh outcome, you want them to fall so the lesson can be learned.

Comment: "A valuable lesson" is often used in this situation. I'm not sure there's a a phrase that exactly matches your request.

Comment: It doesn't express a desire for failure, but the phrase "live and learn" is often used retrospectively to describe a ... successful failure.

Answer (score 2):

You want them to [learn something the hard way](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/learn+the+hard+way).

It means to learn something by an unpleasant experience.

Answer (score 1):

***once bitten, twice shy***

> Once hurt, one is doubly cautious in the future. This seemingly old observation, presumably alluding to an animal biting someone, was first recorded in 1894.
>
> [The American Heritage® Idioms Dictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Once+bitten,+twice+shy)
>
> Variations: [***once burned, twice shy***](http://cprouvost.free.fr/fun/A%20Lire/0198606087.pdf) (or ***wary*** or ***warned***.)

***The burned hand teaches best. After that, advice about fire goes to the heart*** (J.R.R. Tolkien)

> [The Two Towers: Being the Second Part of The Lord of the Rings](https://books.google.fr/books?id=12e8PJ2T7sQC&pg=PA584&lpg=PA584&dq=%22burned+hand+teaches+best.+after+that%22&source=bl&ots=JZ2CPJ0qzP&sig=tBzLDnmvEQ0ar6hJO46jlNNBfts&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjFsPHG-8fMAhWDcBoKHZgNCdEQ6AEIIjAD#v=onepage&q=%22burned%20hand%20teaches%20best.%20after%20that%22&f=false)

Answer (score 0):

I would say '[didactic](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/didactic) failure':  didactic comes from the Latin verb *doceo*, meaning 'I teach'. As for wanting this to happen, I don't believe there is such a word in the English language, although the German loanword *schadenfreude* means taking pleasure from someone else's failure, so perhaps you could work out some combination between the two.

Answer (score 0):

What about "CORRECTIONAL SUFFERANCE"? I wish him to undergo this correctional sufferance so that he may not falter again. It is no reprisal but revisionary.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps "(I'm going to) Let them(him/her) make their(his/her) own mistakes"?

Generally I would use this phrase for a situation that I don't think is terribly damaging, but serves a good purpose as I don't feel like the lesson will be learned any other way.